# Memory leak in node script to delete files in a directory?

Tags: javascript, node.js, memory-leaks

I use the following code to delete files that have not been accessed in more than 15 days in the subdirectores of a directory.  The code works, however memory used by the process climbs to over 2gb, and is not released afterwards.  So there is obviously a memory leak, but for the life of me I cannot tell what.  How should I be doing this differently?

```
readDirectories();

function readDirectories() {
    fs.readdir( dirPath, function( err, subDirs ) {
        if ( err ) return console.log( err );
        subDirs.forEach(function( subDir ) {
            var subDirPath = dirPath + subDir + "/";
            fs.stat( subDirPath, function( err, stat ) {
                if ( err ) return console.log( err );
                if ( stat && stat.isDirectory() ) readFiles( subDirPath );
            });
        });
    });
}

function readFiles( directory ) {
    fs.readdir( directory, function( err, files ) {
        if ( err ) return console.log( err );
        files.forEach(function( file ) {
            checkFile( directory + file );
        });
    });
}

function checkFile( path ) {
    fs.stat( path, function( err, stat ) {
        if ( err ) return console.log( err );
        if ( stat && stat.isFile() ) {
            var livesUntil = new Date();
            livesUntil.setDate( livesUntil.getDate() - 15 );
            if ( stat.atime < livesUntil ) {
                fs.unlink( path, function( err ) {
                    if ( err ) return console.log( err );
                });
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what is going on, but you can check out the npm module fs-extra, which allows you to remove a file, as opposed to just unlinking the file. It could be that the unlinking is keeping the file in memory, you could also try to fs.close the file after you've read or checked it. Hope that helps.

Comment: Is this the entire script? If so, it should exit fairly quickly, so it's possible the garbage collector never gets a chance to run and there's no leak. Although 2gb seems huge. Are there a lot of dirs? Suspect there's more going on here than meets the eye.

Comment: Pretty much -- it is wrapped in node-crontab, so it gets called at intervals, and the process does not exit.  But there's not much more to it.

Comment: that's node-crontab making that leaks, constantly creating objects and closures, I had same issue with it. Just try to use setInterval and monitor leaks

Comment: You are right - it is crontab.  If I just use setInterval the problem goes away.    I guess I will try a different node cron module.  thnx!